# Unable to access webservice using SOAP UI for requests sent through a webserver which is protected by Siteminder

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, soapui, siteminder

We have a webservice hosted on `Tomcat` app server which is fronted by a `Apache` webserver. This webserver is protected by sideminder . The webservice is implemented using `JAX WS 2`.

When i try to access the webservice using `SOAP UI` `3.6.1` with the authorized username and password I get a `403` forbidden error, though I am able to access the `WSDL` through a browser after entering the credentials.

Wrote a `Java` client but get the same error, even after using the `Authenticator` class.

How can i access this webservice using `SOAP UI`.

The issue could be that the webserver is rejecting requests because the SITEMINDER cookie is not present in the `SOAP UI` request. Would there be a way to attach a siteminder cookie in the `SOAP UI` Request.

Comment: Don't use sideminder it is an antithesis to webservices which are intended to be public.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ? [change in headers and attachments in soapui and in wsdl](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html)

Comment: For more googling, you can refer this book which will be (/is ) relased ... http://www.packtpub.com/web-services-testing-with-soapui/book

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on user1640065 answer , you may have to manually add the Basic Authentication header with Base64 encoded userid:password values.  I did not test this with Soap UI, but had the same problem accessing web services API secured by SiteMinder.

Comment: Yes. Thanks the Base 64 user / password , fixed the issue with the Java Client.